# Are these estimators of $P(X<Y)$ asymptotically normally distributed?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, asymptotics

I have two continuous random variables, $X$ and $Y$, whose distributions are unknown. I can draw samples from them and in particular, I am interested in estimating $P(X<Y)$ based on those samples. Let's assume that each sample has $n$ elements: $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are drawn from $X$ and $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ from $Y$.

Can I use $$T=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}I(x_i < y_j)$$
as the estimate of $P(X<Y)$ if I assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent and is such an estimator asymptotically normally distributed? If I knew

Also, if I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, can I use $$S=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I(x_i < y_i)$$ as the estimator of said probability and is it asymptotically normally distributed?

I'm asking about asymptotic normality because I would like to determine lower and upper bounds of $P(X<Y)$ and think that confidence intervals can act as such.

P.S. $I(E)=1$ if $E$ is true, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: You can apply the Central Limit Theorem directly to $S$ because it's the sum of bounded iid variables.  (Indeed, it is proportional to a Binomial$(n, \Pr(X\lt Y))$ distribution.)   It takes a little bit more work to apply it to $T$ directly because the variables, although identically distributed and bounded, are correlated.  However, you can compute their variance-covariance matrix explicitly, which gives one way to draw the conclusion (as well as figure out the bounds). Of greatest interest, perhaps, is the question whether $T$ is any better an estimator than $S$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. If I may ask a follow-up question, how would the variance-covariance matrix help me figure out the bounds? If you can point me out to some good tutorials or excerpts from books, I'd be very grateful. :)

Comment: All you need to know about any Normal distribution is its mean and variance; the bounds you refer to will depend on the variance.  The variance-covariance matrix of the $n^2$ variables $I(x_i\lt y_j)$ determines the variance of $T$. When $n$ is large enough to make $T$ approximately Normal, then you have all the information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statistic $T$ is an example of a general $U$-statistic, introduced
by Hoeffding in his 1948 paper *A class of statistics with asymptotically
normal distribution*. Moreover, it is among the most famous of that class,
namely the *Mann-Whitney U test*. It has lower mean
squared error than $S$, for it equals $E\left(S\mid X_{\left(1\right)},X_{\left(2\right)},\ldots,Y_{\left(1\right)},Y_{\left(2\right)},\ldots\right)$,
and since the order statistics are sufficient, the [Rao-Blackwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%5C%E2%5C%80%5C%93Blackwell_theorem)
can be applied. Furthermore, it is normally distributed, a fact that
follows from a general theorem on $U$-statistics, see the chapters
on $U$-statistics in e.g. Lehmann's [*Elements of Large Sample
Theory*](https://books.google.no/books?id=cNIRBwAAQBAJ%5C&printsec=frontcover%5C&dq=lehmann+large+sample)
or Serfling's [*Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics*](https://books.google.no/books?id=enUouJ4EHzQC%5C&printsec=frontcover%5C&dq=serfling+approximation+theorems).
Its limiting distribution, with a small sample correction, can be
found on [wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%5C%E2%5C%80%5C%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction), and it is implemented in R through the function $\mathtt{wilcox.test}$ (with the option $\mathtt{paired=FALSE}$).

Note that the definition of the Mann-Whitney U test is ambiguous. Sometimes it is defined as the $T$ above, but sometimes it counts "victories for $x_i$" as positive and "victories for $y_i$" as negative. This is the approach taken in e.g. the R function $\mathtt{wilcox.test}$.

Comment: I font think it's ambiguous, but it can be defined in terms of one condition or its complement, depending on which ordering is of interest (e.g., higher scores are better).

Comment: The confidence interval may be calculated using a logit transformation to ensure that the bounds remain in the interval [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly straightforward and intuitive argument for both estimators being asymptotically normal.

Call $$T(X|y_1)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(x_i>y_1)$$

As with $S$, central limit theorem implies this is asymptotically normal.

Furthermore, take $$T = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} T(X|y_i)$$

Since each $T(X|y_i)$ is asymptotically normal, and any linear combination of normal variables is normal, $T$ must too be asymptotically normal.